# Checkbox vs Radio Button

Tags: html, user-interface, checkbox, radio-button

Hopefully this won't be too much of an opinion question, if it is, I apologize:

I presented an idea to the UI lead for our project. I am a developer and mainly handle server-side coding, but occasionally dabble in the UI. There is a section on our webpage where the users are only allowed to select one option from a group of options (in our case, brands, when filtering search results). From this group of options, the user may only select 1. That is, if you select 1, any other selected choice is unchecked.

The UI developer implemented these brand choices as checkboxes, and I suggested that they be implemented as radio buttons, since only 1 can be selected from the group at a time.

For some reason, I always associated checkboxes with multiple choices allowed (usually), and radio buttons were used for things that were mutually exclusive, only 1 could be chosen.

Is there any UI/UX design standards or conventions that supports my stance, or am I wrong, is this simply a preference? The UI designer seemed to think that I was way off base in my suggestion.

Comment: yeah I agreed, because if the choice is one always we have to go for user perspective. because they should provide best answer from our choices. So if it is check boxes they may select more than one. 
But in your case you already mentioned if you select 1, any other selected choice is unchecked.
anyhow we can implement it using radio button simply in my opinion.
and also user mistakenly select something from the check box he need to click one more time to dis select but radio button make it simple if we select something different it automatically unchecked all. Than you. and

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion none of the approach is wrong, in fact any of both can be used since we ultimately need to allow user select only one option out of all BUT it all comes down to the degree of customisation and possibility of extensions. In fact 3rd approach could also be using dropdown.

But if I had to choose one of these 3 approach, I would go for the Checkbox approach because of following reasons:

1. **It gives freedom to change.** Let's consider in case if in future we ever need to allow user choosing multiple options, checkbox wouldn't need to be replaced. In fact one filter component can be made and it can take option if we need to choose one or multiple and behave accordingly.
2. **Users are familiar with checkbox.** Let's admit this we all learn from the leaders, apps like Amazon allow filter through checkbox and users are familiar with that pattern.

In case of radio button the possibility of customisation does lack while I discourage using the dropdown (3rd approach I mentioned above) as user won't be able to see all the options in case of dropdown.